# Will any more question-answer websites be launched?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-exchange

Now that I have a place to ask all my software, programming and web server related questions, I wonder about more computer-related fields that could benefit from SO-like websites and their community.

- Graphic design
- Video and Audio editing
- 3D modeling and CAD

Will any more such question-answer websites be setup by Jeff and Co?

Comment: Check mark race: 3, 2, 1, go!

Answer (score 3):

Yes; they're being set up at [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com) through the new Stack Exchange 2.0 system. The existing accepted answer to this question was correct when it was posted a year and a half ago, when the team was promoting Stack Exchange 1.0. Though the names are similar, the products are quite different.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and Yes. Especially with the popularity of StackOverflow, many different organizations/groups will be launching items similar to it around their specific interests. I'm just waiting for the Photoshop one. Learned of PHPQandA.com today - but it is getting destroyed by traffic apparently.

I don't think the most interesting question is "will other sites be launched." I think the most interesting question is around who will create the best alternative to StackExchange so others can create their own sites.

Comment: How can I find them? Will they be linked on the superhero bar at the page bottom?

Comment: You didn't specify in your question that you meant SO-owned sites.

Comment: PHPQandA could do with some people answer their questions with all the errors they're spitting out.

Comment: If they become a part of the League of Justice they will be listed on the site, otherwise it will be a case of following the list at http://meta.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Jeff has mentioned several times on the podcast (as well as in the [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq)) that [Super User](https://superuser.com/) should not contain questions about videogames or consoles.  Maybe that's just not part of their vision for Super User, but it leads me to believe that they are planning on doing a gaming-themed site next.